# Function returning all columns from more than one table (PostgreSQL)

Tags: function, postgresql, join, return, multiple-tables

I want to create a function that returns all columns from let's say 2 tables that are joined in the function's query. If that was only one table I could simply use table's name to define a return type. For more tables the only way I know to go about it would be to define each column separately which becomes a bit complicated when I have a lot of columns in the tables. Is there a way to do that simpler?

Comment: Copying the column names from the CREATE TABLE statement is a bit longer. It's not really complicated, though.

Comment: You could create a composite type (or use `RETURNS TABLE`) which *has* composite types as fields. Accessing table columns will be longer, but you don't have to copy columns (and their types) + changes in the original table's structure will be immediately reflected + duplicate column names are *allowed* this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create a view and use it as a type:

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS select * from table1, table2, table3;
```

Then this function declaration would work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION multiple_tables(...) RETURNS SETOF viewname AS
$$
  return select * from table1 join table2 on (...) join table3 on (...) WHERE ...;
$$ language sql;
```

`RETURNS viewname` without `SETOF` is possible too.

The function will depend on `viewname` so that the view cannot be later structurally modified without dropping the function first.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dedicated feature for that.

You either list all columns in a [`RETURNS TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html) clause:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
...
RETURNS TABLE (col1 type1, col2 type2, ...)
...
```

Or you create a `TYPE` and use `RETURNS SETOF ..`

```
CREATE TAPE mytype (col1 type1, col2 type2, ...);

...
RETURNS SETOF mytype
...
```